# How can I close the window after the download is complete

Tags: jquery

How can I close the window after the download is complete

```
<html>
<hide>
  <script>
  $(function(){
   $("a").attr({
        "onclick":"javascript:window.close()",
        "target":"open"
        });

     $("a").click(function(){
     $("span").html("redy");
 });
  });

  </script>
</head>

<body>

<span></span> <br />
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I want after that loads the page closes the window

But do not close the window

But only loads the page in a new window only

I want after the end of the download page, close the window

......................

**To illustrate more**

I want when you press the button  It opens a new page and after opening Closes the window

Comment: I am not getting your exact question. what are you trying to download in above code & where is the download window?

Answer (score -1):

Auto-Closing window after downloading is something browser specific. Some Browser allow to check this setting on the download window itself.

```
  <a href="http://www.somesite.com" target="_blank" onClick="javascript:window.close()">
```

this should work fine but it has some issues on fire-fox so you can try a work-around

```
  onClick="javascript: setTimeout(window.close, 10);"
```

setting 10 sec timeout might help but its just a hack there can be better ways of doing this....

Comment: I want when you press the button <a>

It opens a new page and after opening

Closes the window

Comment: The problem is that the new window that opened can not be closed do not know why

I hope you understand me